# Symfony Type error: Argument passed must be an instance of entity or null, ArrayCollection given

Tags: symfony, typeerror, instanceof, arraycollection

I get the following error:

```
Type error: Argument 2 passed to DocumentBundle\Form\SelectionType::DocumentBundle\Form\{closure}() must be an instance of ReferentialBundle\Entity\Channel1 or null, instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection given, called in /srv/http/sp/src/DocumentBundle/Form/SelectionType.php on line 133
```

Unfortunately I don't see my mistake in my FormType.

It looks like that:

```
    class SelectionType extends AbstractType {

      protected $em;

      public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em)
      {
          $this->em = $em;
      }


      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {


          $builder
          ->add('channel1s', EntityType::class, array(

            'class' => 'ReferentialBundle:Channel1',
            'property' => 'name',
            'label' => 'label.channel1s',
            'empty_value' => 'label.select_channel1s',
            'mapped' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'translation_domain' => 'UploadProfile',
            'multiple' => true,
            'required' => false,
          ));

          $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Channel1 $channel1s = null) {
            $channel3s = null === $channel1s ? array() : $channel1s->getChannel3s();

            $form
            ->add('channel3s', EntityType::class, array(
              'class' => 'ReferentialBundle:Channel3',
              'choices' => $channel3s,
            ));
          };
          $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
              $data = $event->getData();
              $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getChannel1s()[0]);
            }
          );
          $builder->get('channel1s')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
              $channel1s = $event->getForm()->getData();

              $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $channel1s);

            }

            );

            $builder
            ->add('agencies', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Agency',
            'property' => 'agent_name',
            'label' => 'label.agencies',
            'empty_value' => 'label.select_agency',
            'expanded' => false,
            'translation_domain' => 'UploadProfile',
            'multiple' => true,
            ));
        }
      public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
      {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
          'data_class' => 'DocumentBundle\Entity\UploadProfile',
          'em' => null,

        ));
      }


      public function getName()
      {
          return 'uploadprofile';
      }
    }
```

The error is for the $channel1s variable in this line:

```
 $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $channel1s);
```

Channel1 has a ManyToMany Relationship to the Uploadprofile Entity.

### Edit

Here's the dump:

```
ArrayCollection {#1828 ▼
  -elements: array:1 [▼
    0 => Channel1 {#1812 ▼
      #id: "C"
      #translationKey: "name.c"
      #name: "Consolidator"
      -uploadProfiles: PersistentCollection {#1895 ▼
        -snapshot: []
        -owner: Channel1 {#1812}
        -association: array:16 [ …16]
        -em: EntityManager {#456 …11}
        -backRefFieldName: "channel1s"
        -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#1810 …}
        -isDirty: false
        #collection: ArrayCollection {#1896 ▼
          -elements: []
        }
        #initialized: false
      }
      #channel3s: PersistentCollection {#1879 ▼
        -snapshot: []
        -owner: Channel1 {#1812}
        -association: array:15 [ …15]
        -em: EntityManager {#456 …11}
        -backRefFieldName: "channel1"
        -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#1748 …}
        -isDirty: false
        #collection: ArrayCollection {#1878 ▼
          -elements: []
        }
        #initialized: false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a `Channel1` object to your formModifier, here you pass `$event->getForm()->getData()`, which is not a channel1 type

Comment: ok and how would I do that? with get Data I thought I'll get the data I selected in my form row for Channel1?

Comment: what have you when you do a dump of your $event->getForm()->getData() ?

Comment: ArrayCollection {#1828 ▼
  -elements: array:1 [▶]
}

that's the output

Comment: can you show ALL the dump, so we could see the type and all

Comment: Oops sorry, I've never used it before and didn't know that you can expand!
I will add it to the post!

Comment: ok so you clearly see that you don't have a channel1 object but an arrayCollection, which is logic because you have multiple entitytype field. so you can't have a channel1 object in your formModifier. you have to change your code

Comment: Yes I definitely get that but I don't understand how to do it. 
I absolutely need the multiple select for my tasks, so it's not supposed to be only one Channel1 object. 
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: remove the type channel1 on the formModifier and ask for a formCollection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153046/discussion-between-sonja-and-t-n-y).

Comment: I've moved that in a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153046/discussion-between-sonja-and-t-n-y) ok? :)

Answer (score 0):

For taking a object channel1 from arraycollection you must replace the code below :

```
channel1s = $event->getForm()->getData();

$formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $channel1s);
```

by

```
channel1s = $event->getForm()->getData()->first();

$formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $channel1s);
```